# Convert number to list of digits

Tags: scheme, racket

How do I convert a number to a list of digits?

I am currently doing:

```
;; (num->list 12345) -> '(1 2 3 4 5)
(define (num->list n)
  (local 
    ((define (num->list n)
       (map (lambda (c)
              (char->num c))
            (string->list (number->string n))))

    (define (char->num c)
      (- (char->integer c) 48)))

    (num->list n)))
```

but would like to know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [digits](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/standard-prelude/#digits) function of my Standard Prelude:

```
(define (digits n . args)
  (let ((b (if (null? args) 10 (car args))))
    (let loop ((n n) (d '()))
      (if (zero? n) d
          (loop (quotient n b)
                (cons (modulo n b) d))))))
```

Your version of the function goes back-and-forth between strings and numbers; my version is purely arithmetic. My version also provides for bases other than decimal.

Comment: Ugh, manual argument unpacking. :-( Thankfully, Racket implements SRFI-89-style optional arguments (as demonstrated in my post), and this question is tagged as Racket-specific. :-D

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I'd do it in Racket:

```
(require srfi/1 srfi/26)
(define (digits->list num (base 10))
  (unfold-right zero? (cut remainder <> base) (cut quotient <> base) num))
```

This is the sort of problem `unfold` was designed for. :-D

Answer (score 1):

"Better" is always open to definition, but a bit more direct/obvious way would be something like this:

```
(define (int->list n) (if (zero? n) `()
                          (append (int->list (quotient n 10)) (list (remainder n 10)))))
```

As to whether this is "good", "bad", "better", etc., I guess it depends on what you want. There's no question that you can find code that's more efficient, more versatile, etc. (in fact, @user448810 has already posted some). This is more what I'd think of as example code for something like an introduction to Scheme -- the emphasis is on being simple and easy to understand/explain<sup>1</sup>. I'd expect that almost anybody with a *bare* minimum of exposure to some Lisp-like language and a general idea of how such numeric conversion is done should be able to figure out everything that's going on here fairly quickly/easily.

---

1. Even at the expense of incorrect behavior for some corner cases -- e.g., as-is, it only even attempts to work correctly for strictly positive numbers.

Comment: Except, `append` + `list` is an antipattern in Scheme programming (`cons` + `reverse` is much more orthodox, though in this example no `reverse` is necessary). So, I wouldn't consider it a suitable "introduction to Scheme" example. :-(

Answer (score -2):

```
;(n-to-list n) convert Num n into a list of its digits
;n-to-list: Num -> (listof Num)
(define (n-to-list n)
  (cond
    [(= n 0) empty]
    [else (cons (remainder n 10) (n-to-list (quotient n 10)))]))
```