# number of times a digit appear

Tags: scheme, racket

Ok, I took scheme last semester, and I Know you can't be so good at scheme within one semester. A friend asked me how I could count the number of times a certain digit comes in a number. I know how to do if it was a list. At first I thought it was a simple use of either inbuilt quotient or remainder, but didnt end up what it seemed like to me. For instance, how can I count number of times five appears in a number: (numfives 125458563) should return 3. Any help is appreciated.

P.s: I am not helping him with his hw, I am doing this for myself. I like challenges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible way: convert the `number` parameter to a list of chars and count the number of chars equal to the char corresponding to the `digit` received as a parameter:

```
(define (num-digits number digit)
  (let ((n (number->string number))
        (d (integer->char (+ (char->integer #\0) digit))))
    (count (lambda (x) (char=? x d))
           (string->list n))))
```

Another way to write the above procedure, shorter but harder to read:

```
(define (num-digits number digit)
  (count (curry char=? (integer->char (+ (char->integer #\0) digit)))
         (string->list (number->string number))))
```

Yet another alternative would be to process each digit in turn by means of arithmetic operations as in @ChrisJester-Young's answer, but taking into account the edge case where both the number and the digit are exactly zero, and avoiding the redefinition of the built-in `count` procedure - also bear in mind that this will only work for integer numbers >= 0 and in base 10. Here's how:

```
(define (num-digits number digit)
  (if (= number digit 0)
      1
      (let loop ((num number)
                 (counter 0))
        (cond ((zero? num)
               counter)
              ((= digit (remainder num 10))
               (loop (quotient num 10) (add1 counter)))
              (else
               (loop (quotient num 10) counter))))))
```

The string-based solutions above might seem a bit clunky, but are shorter to write and have the additional advantages of working for negative numbers, numbers with decimals, numbers in bases different from 10, etc. Anyway, this will work in any version:

```
(num-digits 125458563 5)
> 3
```

And this will work with the string-based versions:

```
(num-digits -123.1234152 1)
> 3
```

Comment: 48 sounds a little too magical. What if they're not on an ASCII-based system? Better to use `(char->integer #\0)`. Even that assumes all the digits are represented contiguously, though.

Comment: I am still wondering if there is one that doesn't do the count for any digit and just target a particular number like my example. (numfives 255353) returns 3. Someone who I trust his Math skills said to me, its not possible for find a formula for that. Like shouldn't have two arguments in the case above (number, digits). I thought that was easier initially, but sounds more hectic now.

Comment: Well, you could write a specialized function for each case in terms of the more general solution. For example, this procedure will count only fives: `(define (numfives number) (num-digits number 5))`

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. Good and easy approach, didn't look at it that way. Between on your previous procedure, you used "add1" I had to change it to (+ 1). didn't know "add1" worked in scheme.

Answer (score 3):

Using `string->list` to turn the string into a list of characters. Then proceed as you would with a list, which you say you already know how to do. (You can use various formatting functions to convert the number to a string.)

Answer (score 2):

I dislike all of the string-based solutions.

The best way to do it, in my view, is to look at each digit by dividing (and modding) by 10 at each stage, then comparing. Example:

```
(define (count-digit num digit)
  (let loop ((num num)
             (count 0))
    (if (zero? num) count
        (loop (quotient num 10)
              (+ count (if (= digit (remainder num 10)) 1 0))))))
```

Comment: The above solution will fail for this edge case: `(count-digit 0 0)` it returns zero, but the correct answer is one.

Comment: Also, you're redefining the built-in `count` procedure.

Comment: +1 this is how I'd do it too, but it won't work for negative numbers without (abs num) and it won't work for floats either, where as the the string versions do

Comment: What if it's not an integer? What if you want to use a different base? This question is fundamentally about the textual representation of the number, thus (IMO) a string is the best way to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Than convert a number to a list and than find out number of a times a digit is appearing in a number.
For converting a number into a list [See this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014453/convert-number-to-list-of-digits)