# list of digits of a number

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am trying to write a function which takes a number and returns a list of the number's digits. For example:

```
(list-num 648)
;=> (6 4 8)
```

I have written some code, but it returns `(8 4 6)`, and I can't use `reverse`.  MY code so far:

```
(define (list-num n)
  (if (not (equal? (quotient n 10) 0))
      (cons (modulo n 10) (list-num(quotient n 10)))
      (cons (modulo n 10) '())))
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate.  Some related questions include:  [Converting a list of digits to a number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19554279/1281433), which goes in the other direction; and [Improving performance for converting numbers to lists, and base10 to base2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19822227/1281433), which involves transforming numbers to lists of digits.

Comment: Here we go:  this is duplicate of [Convert number to list of digits](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8014453/1281433).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your function as the inner function and wrap an outer function that does the reverse:

```
(define (list-num n)
  ; inner function - your initial function      
  (define (sub n)
    (if (not (equal? (quotient n 10) 0))
        (cons (modulo n 10) (sub (quotient n 10)))
        (cons (modulo n 10) '())))
  ; call inner function
  (reverse (sub n)))
```

then

```
> (list-num 648)
'(6 4 8)
```

You could also use a *named let* and an accumulator:

```
(define (list-num n)
  (let loop ((n n) (acc '())) ; named let, acc=accumulator
    (let ((q (quotient n 10)) (r (remainder n 10)))
      (if (= q 0)
          (cons r acc)
          (loop q (cons r acc))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Common Lisp:

```
CL-USER 21 > (map 'list #'digit-char-p (princ-to-string 648))
(6 4 8)
```